# Visual Basic isn't accepting my file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, audio

I am currently using Visual Basic 2010.  I am creating a replica of the game "Simon", I have all the code down but I would like the game to play a sound while flashing the color.  I tried using various solutions online, including built in functions but they all caused immense lag and ruined the fun of the game.  I would like to try adding a downloaded sound and I found various .wav files that should work, however when I try adding it to my resources visual basic refuses to display it in the folder I saved it to.  I have tried renaming it and moving it to other files and triple checked that they truly were .wav files.  Help

Answer (score 0):

I continued fooling around with my resource files and I realized it was preset to only search for text files... As soon as I changed it to search for audio it worked right away.